# Are multi-character-to-single-character collations possible in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a MySQL database. Every record contains a title. Some of the records contain the title `Edelweiss` with a double `s` and others contain the title `Edelweiß` with an eszett.

I want users to be able to search for either string and get back all results for either spelling.

With my current collation -- utf8_general_ci -- it looks like `ß` is equivalent to `s`. Is there a way to make `ß` equivalent to `ss`, so that searching for `ss` will yield results containing `ß`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) :

`utf8_general_ci` considers `s=ß`
`utf8_general_mysql500_ci` says `ß` comes after `Z`
All other `utf8` Collations treat `ss` and `ß` as equal.

So, change the Collation of (at least) the column.

Note:  all the `_general_` collations look at only one character at a time.  Most other collations are more complex.  Another example is whether `ae=æ` or `æ` is treated as a separate "letter".

Answer (score 0):

This solution below Works, but might not be the best

```
SELECT *,replace(fullname,'ss','ß') rep1,replace(fullname,'ß','ss') rep2 
FROM test
HAVING rep1 like '%ß%' or rep2 like '%ß%';

OR

SELECT *,replace(fullname,'ss','ß') rep1,replace(fullname,'ß','ss') rep2 
FROM test
HAVING rep1 like '%ss%' or rep2 like '%ss%';
```

Essentially, i created two column that replaces the `ss` to `ß` and another `ß` to `ss`
and filter using a combination of `HAVING` And `LIKE` to filter the result.

You could Also Write it like this

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE replace(fullname,'ss','ß') 
LIKE '%ß%' or replace(fullname,'ß','ss') like '%ß%';
```

NOTE: You Can Replace the parts where I write '%ß%' into the search u need. for example '%Edelweiß%'